# R boxplot and stripchart side-by-side in 1 figure

Tags: r, boxplot, stripchart

Is it possible to plot a boxplot and a stripchart next to each other in the same figure? If I run this code, the stripchart overrides the boxplots. What i actually want is that they lay next to each other. In hat way a figure with 10 column on the x-as will be formed. Is that possible?

```
boxplot(doubles[1:5,])
stripchart(doubles[6:10,],add=TRUE,vertical=TRUE, pch=19)
```

[image]

Comment: It will be easier for people to give better feedback if you give us a snippet of `doubles` via `dput(doubles)` or `dput(head(doubles,20)` if the data is too long.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some example of you data would be good, but the easiest option is probably:

```
 #random data corresponding to your 5 columns    
 x <- data.frame(V = rnorm(100), W = rnorm(100), X = rnorm(100), Y = rnorm(100), 
     Z = rnorm(100))
 #remove axis with 'axes=F', define wider x-limits with 'xlim' 
 stripchart(x[1:5,],vertical=TRUE, pch=19,xlim=c(1,6),axes=F)
 #add boxplots next to stripchart, decrease width with 'boxwex'
 boxplot(x[1:5,],add=T,at=1.5:5.5,boxwex=0.25,axes=F)
 #add custom x axis
 axis(1,at=1.25:5.25,labels=names(x))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks to Geek On Acid, This solution is that I am looking for!

Answer (score 4):

Use `ggplot2`

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(treatment, decrease, data = OrchardSprays) + 
  scale_y_log10() + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  geom_point(colour = 'blue', alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]